# Check if Object array has certain key

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

So I'm updating and fixing my text adventure engine I made in AS3. The first thing I wanted to do is fix how it handles checking if the part of the story you are on has choices you have to choose from.

The way I did this before was checking if the current story part you had on screen had the words "What do you do?", if that was true then it would display the choices.

I want to change it so it displays choices if the key choices exists the Object array (is that what you call it? Forgive me if it's not the correct terminology

Here's the object array and with the first part of the story having choices and how I currently check to see if I should display choices:

```
public var parts:Object = 
{

    "0":
        {
            "text":"Testing new engine and stuffz",
            "choices":
                {
                    "response1":
                        {
                            "text":"Brutal.",
                            "nextPart":"BRUTAL"
                        },
                },
            "Brutal":false, 
            "Kind":false 
        },
    "BRUTAL":
        {
            "text":"That was pretty fuckin' brutal",
            "":""
        }
}



if ( parts[curPart]["text"].indexOf("What do you do?") >= 0) 
{
    //trace(this[currentPart])
    choosing = true
    createOptions();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if `choices` key exists call `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
trace(parts["0"].hasOwnProperty("choice"));// false
trace(parts["0"].hasOwnProperty("choices"));// true
```